# Getting All Combinations or Permutations of a Character using terms

Tags: python, string, combinations, permutation, discrete-mathematics

i want all combinations words of character using terms. Example :

`word = 'aan'`

`result = ['ana', 'naa', 'aan']`

terms :

number of character 'a' -> 2

number of character 'n' -> 1

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a one liner solution, and give the result in a list

You can use permutation tools from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) package to get all of the permutations (not combinations) solutions

```
from itertools import permutations
word = 'aan'
list(set([ ''.join(list(i)) for i in permutations(word,len(word))]))
```

Comment: not working to word = 'ain'. the result = ['ain', 'ani', 'nai']

Comment: the one that you ask in the first place is more into permutations rather than to combinations, try to play with itertools package and use the method that suit to your problems. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand what you want, I would do it like that:

```py
from itertools import permutations

result = set()
for combination in permutations("aan"):
    result.add(combination)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
from collections import Counter
def combo(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == len(d):
    yield ''.join(c)
  else:
    _c1, _c2 = Counter(d), Counter(c)
    for i in d:
      if _c2.get(i, 0) < _c1[i]:
        yield from combo(d, c+[i])

word = 'aan'
print(list(set(combo(word))))
```

Output:

```
['aan', 'naa', 'ana']
```

---

```
word = 'ain'
print(list(set(combo(word))))
```

Output:

```
['ina', 'nia', 'nai', 'ani', 'ian', 'ain']
```